# Using a single broadband connection to connect internet to 2 systems

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, internet

I have a laptop connected to internet through broadband connection via ethernet cable from router. I want to run internet on another computer(desktop), So that I can use internet on both simultaneously. How can I connect both the system to internet without introducing a new device. [My router has an additional USB output besides ethernet output]

Comment: More info is needed regarding your modem/router and computer hardware being used.  Or you could buy a simple, inexpensive router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a switch or router. What you probably have is a cable modem, and without having multiple ethernet ports on it, there isn't really an easy way to do it. The $20 it would cost to get a switch at a local electronic store would cause a lot less headache than setting up an ad-hoc wireless network (if both computers have wireless, if not you would have to spend even more money on a wireless adapter) and setting up internet sharing. Plus, with internet sharing you have to have both computers on for it to work on the tethered one, which may or may not be an issue.

Comment: 100% agree with your statement. A low investment solution.

Answer (score 1):

The extra USB port is an either/or, not both. You could use Internet Connection Sharing, but really, I recommend that if you can somehow, just get an intermediate wireless router with an incorporated switch. Windows 7 has removed this feature, so you need to use the other computer to be the primary if it is running Vista or XP.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126

Comment: could you clarify how can I enable Internet Connection Sharing ?

Comment: That is what the links were for. They give step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do to get two machines online with the same internet connection is to just hook a switch up to your modem and attach a separate Ethernet cable to each machine.

Here is a simple switch example: [Linksys EtherFast 10/100 5-Port Workgroup Switch EZXS55W Switch - 5 ports](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=linksys+switch&hl=en&prmd=ivns&resnum=2&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1190&bih=778&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=6935468566331435688&sa=X&ei=EiPuTdvKAYHz0gHVzrmcCA&ved=0CGcQ8wIwAQ)

No configuration is needed for either the modem or the computers. Just hook the cables up and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps some.

Comment: Your comment is not correct. A pure switch will not work: Otherwise, you have two or more computers trying to use the same IP...a no-no. You need one that has routing capability to take the one IP one one network and route the traffic to multiple IP's on an internal network.

Comment: That's odd, because this is the type of setup I have with 5+ computers. All have different IP addresses and all connect to the internet via the same modem.

Comment: A switch will work, that is what they are for? The switch is connected to the router/modem that does DHCP. I suppose there are some modems that would require a router instead of a switch.

Comment: A switch and a router are similar things but are not the exact samething.  The user wants a router not a switch.

Comment: No where does he says he wants a router, what he does say is "without introducing a new device". But one of the easiest solutions would be to go with a switch. While you may be able to find a router that does everything also, you would probably be dropping a few more dollars than with a simple switch.